# Replace the contents of DIV in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have some angular code as follows:

```
sb = "<p>Test<p>";
app.controller("CaseBatches", function ($scope, $sce) {
                $scope.tabs = $sce.trustAsHtml(sb);
    });
```

Now on first run I am able to inject the HTML code using $sce service.

I have a button that executes a javascript function that changes the values of sb to say:

```
sb = "<b>Test 1</b>";
```

But when I run the following code again, my DIV contents are not updated.

```
sb = "<b>Test 1</b>";
app.controller("CaseBatches", function ($scope, $sce) {
                $scope.tabs = $sce.trustAsHtml(sb);
    });
```

The DOM is simply not updated. I have tried many different ways such as $sce.trustAsHTML('') before reapplying sb values.

Any help about how to accomplish this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"run the code again"*? Can you create a simple demo that demonstrates the issue? If you click on `<>` in question editor can do it right here in this page

Answer (score 0):

You might need to setup $scope watcher event for it to work.

```
<pre ng-bind-html="tabs"></pre>

sb = "<b>Test 1</b>";
app.controller("CaseBatches", function ($scope, $sce) {
                   
        $scope.$watch('sb', function(v) {
            if (v) {
                // Render the tabs as trusted HTML
                 $scope.tabs = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.sb);
            }
        })             
                                    
    });
```